# Universal app and AdMediation - testing different ad sizes?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-10, uwp

I'm trying to use the `Microsoft Advertising Universal SDK`. Inside this SDK there exist an `AdMediatorControl` which I dragged to an empty page inside the test app, but how do I test different ad sizes (160x600, 250x250 etc)? When I used the `AdControl` I could set the `AdUnit` property to test different sizes, but now I cant. And since I can't find any proper documentation for what is possible with the `AdMediator`..it's extra hard.

I tried explicitly settings the width and height, but that won't make any difference. This is what I get:

> [image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this make any difference to the test ads, but you can control the size of the ad within the control by using the following the code:

```
AdMediator.AdSdkOptionalParameters[AdSdkNames.MicrosoftAdvertising]["Width"] = 728
AdMediator.AdSdkOptionalParameters[AdSdkNames.MicrosoftAdvertising]["Height"] = 90
```

However, the only time I've found this necessary with real ads is when using AdDuplex in the 8.1 version of the control.

As for the documentation, you can find it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt219691.aspx